# Ionic 4: error when I try to run my project with ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework

I've been trying to use ionic for a long time but I still can not get it yet I have the right version of node and npm

```
node --version 10.13.0 in (LTS)

npm - version 6.4.0
```

And I followed the installation procedure but when I try to make ionic serve I am shown the following errors

1-- `error can not find @ angular / CLI`

I fix it with: `npm install -g @ angular / CLI`

2-- `error can not find @ angular-devkit / built`

3 - `error can not find @ angular / compile-cli`

It does not end the mistakes and she tired me a lot

I searched everywhere I watched tutorials, ask questions in ionic forum, StackOverFlow.

But really no solution until now

Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to compile an ionic3 or ionic4 project? 
What type of project did you select?  https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/cli/start

Comment: I'm using Ionic 4